# Align Image in LyX

Tags: lyx

I am writing my CV on LyX and I would like to insert my mugshot next to my personal details, which are aligned in the top center of the document. How can I do that without disturbing the text?

I realise this might be a novice question but I am new to LyX.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. And a screenshot of what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Have you used some template for the CV, or is it created from scratch? If the former, can you tell us which template, if the latter can you create an example, and edit your question to include either the exported LaTeX code, or the `.lyx` file itself? (A `.lyx` file is a plain text file, open it in notepad or something, and copy everything.)